# Dependency is not using the correct maven repository

Tags: maven, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying o use the `ManifestClasspath` plugin to solve the `CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long` error. My `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2"
//            allowInsecureProtocol = true
        }
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$springBootVersion")
        classpath "org.owasp:dependency-check-gradle:$dependencyCheckVersion"
        classpath("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-gradle-plugin:${springCloudContractVersion}")
        classpath("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-pact:${springCloudContractVersion}")
        classpath "gradle.plugin.ua.eshepelyuk:ManifestClasspath:1.0.0"
    }
}

ext['elasticsearch.version'] = "7.1.0"

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: "ua.eshepelyuk.ManifestClasspath"
    ...
}
```

But, now I am getting this error:

```
Could not GET 'http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/gradle/plugin/ua/eshepelyuk/ManifestClasspath/1.0.0/ManifestClasspath-1.0.0.pom'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
```

It needs to use the `https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/` repository, but instead it uses `http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2`. How can I specify which repository it needs to use?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line `"http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2"`

into `"https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2"` will fix this problem .

because its already using https with `https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/` , but it will need to search the first `"http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2"` one which is http .